# Обновления в БД

Tags: android, sqlite

Приложение использует готовую БД SQLite. В таблице из БД была пустая колонка, но сейчас я для всех записей в эту колонку добавил строковое значение "0". На телефоне попробовал поработать с приложением выкинуло, видимо потому что после переустановки приложения изменения автоматически не произошли в БД. Скажите как мне сделать так, чтобы у других пользователей, которые скачают приложение не возникало ошибок и БД обновилась? Версию БД нужно изменять? Как обновить эту колонку у других пользователей?

Comment: Правильно ли будет если изменить версию БД и в методе onUpgrade() тупо выполнить обновление нужной колонки через update? или как нужно делать?

Comment: Из общих соображений проверять надо везде, где может возникнуть проблема. А это значит, что как минимум на старте приложения - запрашивать это поле для случайной записи, и если получишь Null, то выполнять UPDATE table SET field='0' WHERE field IS NULL; Это поможет как для неконвертированной БД, так и при сбоях/ошибках.

Comment: Я пробую сделать так. изменил версию БД на 2 и пишу так:

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {
            String s = "0";
            database.beginTransaction();
            try {
                database.execSQL("update tbl set favorites = " + "\"" + s + "\"");
                database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                database.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    }

Не обновляется похоже колонка. Я в чем ошибся?

Comment: А нафига этот геморрой с переменной s? И почему в строку запроса кавычки кладутся двойные? почему не просто database.execSQL("update tbl set favorites = '0'"); ?

Comment: Первый раз пытаюсь обновить БД.. можно и вашим способом. Но и после него не обновилась колонка. Вообще я правильно пытаюсь обновить эту колонку в таблице?

Comment: Вы говорили что нужно в методе onCreate на старте приложения тоже проверять. А разве не хватает того что в методе onUpgrade это делается?

Comment: Запрос с точки зрения SQLite верный (с точностью до особенностей коннектора). А насколько верна конструкция ЯП (кстати, какого?), сказать не могу.

Comment: приложения для андроид java ЯП

Comment: Для стартующего приложения процесс обновления - это давно и неправда. Нет, если есть желание, можно заставить его надеяться, что всё под ним в порядке - но я бы не стал. Тем более что проверка-то по всему копеечная, SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE favorites IS NULL LIMIT 1;, и даже интересен не результат, а просто факт возврата записи.

Comment: Добавил в MainActivity в метод onUpgrade() обновление UPDATE table SET field='0' WHERE field IS NULL и все заработало.  без проверок случайных записей такое обновление сделал.

Comment: Еще такой момент. Приложение использует готовую БД из почти 25 тыс. записей. Если я захочу добавить в БД еще другие записи как в этом случае обновить у пользователей БД? Чтобы из новой версии БД в их БД попали только те записи, которых у них не было?

Comment: бд только для чтения или запись тоже происходит?

Comment: Есть activity где происходят обновления тоже, запись